# Can't get bootstrap tooltip to work in web forms

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am trying to add bootstrap tooltips to an html button with no success.  I have tried numerous examples found across the web, but can't get the tooltip to show up at all.

I have added bootstrap.js, jquery.js and although I heard the tooltip js was included in the bootstrap.js, I downloaded and tried the bootstrap-tooltip.js.

I have tried to initiate the tooltip by referencing a class, and rel=.  The only thing that would make the tooltip show was adding the option show, which makes it show all the time.

Below is my latest try...

```
 <div class="input-xxlarge">
      <div class="input-append">
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStylists" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddStylists_SelectedIndexChanged"
               CssClass="input-xxlarge" DataSourceID="lnqStylists" DataTextField="fullName" DataValueField="StylistID" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Selected="True">---Select Stylist---</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
          <a href="#" class="link" data-original-title="first tooltip">Hover me for a tooltip</a>!
          <button id="btnSchedule" runat="server" data-placement="right" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Send Info" class="button button-basic button-basic-orange">
                    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
          </button> 

      </div>
 </div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.link').tooltip();
</script>

<script src="../Scripts/ease/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/ease/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using html markup `data-toggle` like this and see if it works.

```
<a class="link" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover"
  data-original-title="Some Text!">Hover me!</a>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxnkD/2)

Comment: Don't know why, but didn't work.  I have used a lot of bootstrap in this application, not sure what could be conflicting to cause this not to work.

Comment: Could you post a version (with stripped out asp) to jsFiddle (or just update the one I posted). So that way we could try to replicate the issue?

Comment: First, thanks for your help.  I signed up for jsFiddle and created an example. Hopefully I did it right. http://jsfiddle.net/strager/N2NTm/2/

Comment: Here is yours updated. http://jsfiddle.net/N2NTm/3/ You weren't calling `tooltip()` on your class so it was never initialized. I added the class hoverClass to each and called .tooltip on it. It now works.

Comment: I copied what you had, but it still doesn't work within the application.  I moved 
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $('.hoverClass').tooltip();
</script>
to the top of the page, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @SheriTrager That has to be loaded last. Did you add hoverClass to the button you want to hover?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try initializing the tool tip after the J Query and Bootstrap loaded?

```
<script src="../Scripts/ease/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('.link').tooltip();
```

Get familiar with the developer console across all browsers, you can check for all sorts of things, which also stops you from going mad from these problems